# How To Update VLC Player on Debian?

Tags: vlc

I want to upgrade VLC to 2.2.1 on my Debian machine, but the standard commands below are not doing it.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If I do vlc --version, I see I'm running 2.2.0-rc2 Weatherwax.

Answer (score 2):

Debian doesn't update software in already-released versions of Debian (such as Wheezy and Jessie) just because there's a newer version of that software; if there is a critical bug fix (such as a regression fix for a CVE fix), then that bug fix might become available in all versions of Debian.

That being said, newer versions of software *might* be added to a separate `-backports` repository. This repository is mainly for having newer versions of programs in older releases of Debian. However, note that this isn't an automatic process; someone has to request that a newer version of some package (`vlc`, in this case) be backported to Jessie. Then, someone must build the backport and test it in Jessie to make sure that everything works. You can see more info about using backports [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Backports).

If you want to have the latest version of VLC, you'll either have to download it manually from their website or see if it is in the Debian backports (which it isn't, currently).

Comment: I'm kinda new to Debian so I don't understand what backports is or what I'm trying to do.

Comment: That's pretty accurate; if a security issue turns up in VLC, the fix for that would be added to the package in Jessie, rather than a new version of VLC altogether. Since 2.2.1 is in testing it is eligible for [backports](http://backports.debian.org) and you can request it (`reportbug wnpp` I think).

Comment: gtk-message failed to load module canberra-gtk-module

Comment: Oh I re-read what you put. I just checked on the vlc website and it says "vlc is in testing, but due to the way testing works, we can't guarantee if the latest version is available. Install vlc browser-plugin-vlc the usual way you do it". Whats the usuall way? apt-get?

Comment: You may also use `pinning` to handle multiple version of debian in a single installation. Depending on your config, you could get latest vlc from `testing-9` or `unstable-10`.

Comment: Whats pinning ?

Comment: I've managed to install that plugin but it still don't work. What should I do next?

Comment: @johnsmith: `pinning` is tha ability of apt tool to handle multiple repositories with priorities: http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html